# Hide/show element according to tab group selected index causes error : Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, angular-material

I show / hide button with ngIf:

```
    <div style="width: 100%;height: 40px;">
        <button *ngIf="tabGroup.selectedIndex === 1" mat-button>
           button
        </button>
    </div>
<mat-tab-group  #tabGroup>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

it is work, but there is error in the console - Expression has changed after it was checked.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xfsrnz?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.html)

Answer (score 3):

The tab index will change but the button will already have checked for the `selectedIndex`. 
When running the extra change detection (when you're developing), Angular notices that `tabGroup.selectedIndex === 1` gives a different result. Hence the error you're getting.

I suggest doing a quick search of `Angular Expression has changed after it was checked.` online.

There are a lot of explanations about it and good tutorials/guide on how to avoid it.

A potential fix here is to save the index in a var whenever you change the tab, something like:

```
<div style="width: 100%;height: 40px;">
    <button *ngIf="selected === 0" style="height: 24px;" mat-button >
        button
    </button>
</div>
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected" (selectedIndexChange)="selected = $event" #s>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic use of the tab group
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'tab-group-basic-example',
  templateUrl: 'tab-group-basic-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab-group-basic-example.css'],
})
export class TabGroupBasicExample {

  selected: number = 0
}
```